# Swift - How to create a class-constrained property wrapper?

Tags: swift

I am trying to write a class-constrained property wrapper, much like [`@Published`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) offered by Combine.
For example:

```swift
struct Person {
  // error: 'wrappedValue' is unavailable: @Published is only available on properties of classes
  @Published var age = 0 
}
```

I cannot figure out how to implement this behaviour myself.
Looking at the interface for `Published`, there is no syntax indicating that the property wrapper is class-constrained:

```swift
@propertyWrapper public struct Published<Value> {
  public init(wrappedValue: Value)
  public init(initialValue: Value)
  public struct Publisher : Publisher {
    // ...
  }
  public var projectedValue: Published<Value>.Publisher { mutating get set }
}
```

Somehow the `wrappedValue` is only being made available when the property wrapper is defined in an `AnyObject`.
Because of the error message, it looks like this is making use of `@available` in some way to be able to infer the context where this is defined, and is then making `wrappedValue` conditionally unavailable if so.
Notice the wording of the error message:

```swift
@available(*, unavailable, message: "This is a test")
func foo() {}

foo() // error: 'foo()' is unavailable: This is a test
```

Is it possible to implement this behaviour myself?

```swift
// How to constrain to only use in classes?
@propertyWrapper
struct MyClassWrapper<Value> {
  var state: Value
  var wrappedValue: Value {
    get {
      state
    }
    set {
      state = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the behaviour I've seen, I think it is either simply marked `unavailable` like this:

```
@available(*, unavailable, message: "@Published is only available on properties of classes")
var wrappedValue: Value
```

This is because you cannot access `Published.wrappedValue` from *anywhere*. For example, even this gives the same "unavailable" error:

```
class Bar: ObservableObject {
    @Published var x = ""
    
    func f() {
        // 'wrappedValue' is unavailable: @Published is only available on properties of classes
        print(_x.wrappedValue) 
    }
}
```

Clearly, the error doesn't make much sense here, so it is probably the case that `wrappedValue` itself is marked unavailable.

Properties marked with a property wrapper are usually lowered into a computed property of the wrapped type, and a stored property of the wrapper type, e.g.

```
@Published var x = "foo"
```

is lowered into:

```
var x: String {
    get { _x.wrappedValue }
    set { _x.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
private var _x = Published(wrappedValue: "foo")
```

(Source: [SE-0258](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#proposed-solution))

This is what happens when you try to use `@Published` in a struct, and as you can see, it uses `wrappedValue`, which produces the error. However, when you use `@Published` in a class, I *suspect* that some compiler magic happens, and ***lowers it a different way***, that doesn't involve `wrappedValue`.

The compiler needs to do this special thing for classes, because the class is supposed to inherit `ObservableObject`, and some compiler magic is required so that the default implementation of [`objectWillChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject/objectwillchange-2oa5v) can find all the `@Published` properties.

In any case, it is also possible to write a `Published` implementation that isn't class-bound, but of course you don't get the auto generated `objectWillChange` implementation if you choose to do that. Here is an example adapted from [here](https://medium.com/genetec-tech/property-wrappers-in-swift-5-1-the-missing-published-implementation-1a466ebcf660#98a5).

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Published<T> {
    private var innerSubject = PassthroughSubject<T, Never>()
    
    init(wrappedValue: T) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: T {
        didSet {
            innerSubject.send(wrappedValue)
        }
    }
    var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<T, Never> {
        innerSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing is missing here for this to work you need to add a subscript... Making the wrappedValue unavailable doesn't even work with a class because there is just no way to access the value. A subscript is needed: public static subscript<EnclosingSelf: AnyObject>(
        _enclosingInstance object: EnclosingSelf,
        wrapped wrappedKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<EnclosingSelf, Value>,
        storage storageKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<EnclosingSelf, Published<Value>>
    ) -> Value { get{object[keyPath: storageKeyPath]...} set{object[keyPath: storageKeyPath]...}}

Comment: @Muvimotv Maybe I wasn't very clear in my answer, but my answer boils down to "this (making a class-constrained property wrapper) cannot be done and there is some compiler magic going on with `@Published`". If you disagree with that point, feel free to post another answer. Or are you referring to the final code snippet I included for the non-class-bound `@Published`? I still have no idea what you are on about subscripts though. `@Published` doesn't have subscripts.

Comment: Sweeper, What I'm saying is that is it possible to do it in the same way it's done with @Published. I've done it for my own property wrapper... 
This information your are providing is partially correct, it's missing one key element :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a full answer to the original question and is using the same implementation as Apple uses in their original @Published.

```
@propertyWrapper
public final class Published<Value> {
    
    /// This is here only to allow to have an init() not requiring any parameters
    /// It's not necessary if you don't need that functionality. In that case the publisher below can be created in the init...
    private var initialValue: Value?
    
    private lazy var publisher = CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never>(initialValue!)
    
    /// Published Value
    @available(*, unavailable, message: "@Published is only available on properties of classes")
    public var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            publisher.value
        }
        set {
            if initialValue == nil {
                initialValue = newValue
            }
            
            publisher.send(newValue)
        }
    }
    
    /// Subscript to allow classes to access the wrappedValue
    public static subscript<EnclosingContainer: AnyObject>(
        _enclosingInstance object: EnclosingContainer,
        wrapped wrappedKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<EnclosingContainer, Value>,
        storage storageKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<EnclosingContainer, Published<Value>>
    ) -> Value {
        get {
            object[keyPath: storageKeyPath].publisher.value
        }
        set {
            let object = object[keyPath: storageKeyPath]
            
            if object.initialValue == nil {
                object.initialValue = newValue
            }
            
            object.publisher.send(newValue)
        }
    }
    
    /// This is use when declaring like this: @Published var blabla: Bool
    /// in this case, the default value of blabla needs to be set in the init of the classe
    /// init() {
    ///     blabla = true
    /// }
    public init() { }
    
    /// This is use when declaring like this: @Published var blabla = true
    public init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        initialValue = wrappedValue
    }
}

// MARK: How not to use...

/// Failling as expected because it's not a class
struct Failling {
    /// 'wrappedValue' is unavailable: @Published is only available on properties of classes
    @Published var errorHere: Bool
}

// MARK: How to use...
class Working {
    @Published var workingHere: Bool
    
    init(_ workingHere: Bool) {
        self.workingHere = workingHere
    }
}

class WorkingToo {
    @Published var workingHere = true
    
    /// only here to show this is empty...
    init() {}
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean now, after looking at how [OpenCombine](https://github.com/OpenCombine/OpenCombine) does it, which is similar to your answer here. The `subscript` that you declared here doesn't seem to be a documented feature though... Especially, `_enclosingInstance` has a leading underscore. Do you have a link to some documentation about it.?

Comment: Is this meant to be a full answer to the original question? Or is this just meant to be part of the comments on Sweeper's answer? If this is meant to be a full answer, please provide more than just code. Explain how this answers the question. If this is just a big comment for the other answer, then please do not post comments as answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Pbulished` used an underscore-prefixed language feature, you can learn more about it from [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/accessing-a-swift-property-wrappers-enclosing-instance/).

And you can create a class-constrained property wrapper without underscore-prefixed language feature like this:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct ClassWrapper<T, Value> where T: AnyObject {
    private var state: Value
    
    init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        state = wrappedValue
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { state }
        set { state = newValue }
    }
}

protocol ClassWrappedProtocol: AnyObject {
    typealias ClassWrapped<T> = ClassWrapper<Self, T>
}

class YourClass: ClassWrappedProtocol {
    @ClassWrapped var value = 0
}
```